# Отправка и получение результатов из микросервисов

Tags: python, redis, микросервисы

Всех приветствую. Пытаюсь разобраться в микросервисной архитектуре.

Задача такая: есть 2 сервиса. Первый - к примеру, бронирует номера в отеле. Второй -  что-то типа консольного интерфейса, который отправляет задачу бронирования первому и ждет от него ответ, мол забронирован номер или нет.

Для этой задачи я выбрал redis, как брокера сообщений и базы данных. Но вот незадача:

Для добавления задачи бронирования номера, к примеру, можно использовать list. Но..

- Как второму сервису-интерфейсу получить результат бронирования?
- Забронировался номер или нет?

Какой способ лучше использовать в этой ситуации?

Вроде как, stream тоже сюда подходит. Или же.. pub/sub. Но штука в том, что оба сервиса должны и читать канал и писать в него, а как я почитал, stream нужен только для записи всяких задач.

Как лучше это сделать?

Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: Если используете список (list) в Redis для отправки бронирования, то второй сервис может читать результаты из этого же списка. Для этого можно использовать команды lpush и rpop для задачи в первом сервисе и получения во втором сервисе.
Еще можно использовать механизм pub/sub Redis, чтобы позволить микросервисам писать и читать из канала. В этом случае первый сервис может опубликовать результаты бронирования номера в канале, а второй сервис может подписаться на этот канал, чтобы получать результаты.

Comment: Stream также может использоваться для решения этой задачи, однако это более продвинутый механизм, который потребует большего времени на настройку и обработку, чем list или pub/sub.

Comment: @AleksandrFetisov, хм, но тут момент, если паб / саб упадет - то и номер не забронируется. А в стримах, как я понимаю, задачи сохраняются, верно?

Comment: да, верно, тут лучше всего методом проб и ошибок все делать, и проводить тесты
много всяких если и но

Comment: можно два или три листа использовать и скажем еще хешмапу, в первом задачи на выполение, причем в него кладутся только id задач, а данные для задач складываются под этими же id в хешмапу. когда обработчик выполняет задачу, он дополняет данные в хешмапе результатами, после чего выполняет brpoplpush для переноса задачи из листа ожидания в лист выполненного. А читающий сервис спит на чтении из очереди результатов. Правда это будет плохо работать когда у вас много обработчиков и много обращающихся. Потребуются как минимум отдельные очереди результатов.

Comment: Начинать надо с того, что решите что вы будете делать если сервис бронирования взял задачу и упал. С листами тяжело обеспечить рестарт задач. Стримы это обеспечивают из коробки, но с ними сложно работать. Если нужна надежность то часто приходится использовать несколько типов данных и еще скрипты LUA